# Chaining 'with' statements while returning view

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

so in one of the Ajax calls I want to return the index view of the page with some data, while also sending additional data - the message.

The index view looks something like this:

```
public function index()
{
    // data retrieval

    $data = [
        'groups' => $groups,
        'info' => $info,

    ];
    return view('groups.index')->with('data', $data);
}
```

Now with this Ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.group-delete-fa').click(function() {
        if (confirm('Remove user?')) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var idGroup = $(this).attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                method: "POST",
                url: "/remove_user",
                data: {id: id, idGroup: idGroup },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('body').html(response);
                    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    //alert(errorThrown);
                }       
            });
        }
    })
});
```

I call this function

```
public function removeUser(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->id;
    $idGroup = $request->idGroup;
    $user = User::find($id);

    //$user->groups()->detach($idGroup);

    $view = $this->show($idGroup);
    return $view->with('success', 'User  removed from group')->render();
}
```

The message is parsed like this (in the root jumbotron element):

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{session('success')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

However, the message is not sent along with the `$data` and is not parsed. I guess you can not chain `with()` function like this? How can I send additional data?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are passing the `success` as a variable to the view, not in session.
   Try to change in your root jumbotron element `session('success')` for `$success` check that it exists first with isset.

```
    @if (isset($success))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{$success}}
        </div>
    @endif
```

2. Or do not use ajax and redirect to the same page with the message in session.

Comment: Yeah that's it, dont even know why I used session there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I did this:

```
return redirect('/groups/' . $idGroup)->with('success', 'User removed from the group.');
```

Which works, but is this a good way to do it, if you use Ajax?